# DialogFragment onActivity result never reached

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-nested-fragment

I have the following arrangement: `CatActivity -> FragA -> FragB`; where, `FragA` launches `FragB` using `fragB.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "FragB”);`.

`FragB` launches the gallery intent with

```
Intent img = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
img.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(img, “Choose Photo”),PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The problem is that the `FragB`’s `onActivityResult` is never reached. Does anyone know why?
FYI: neither `CatActivity` nor `FragA` implements its respective `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: Override `onActivityResult()` for `CatActivity` and `FragA`, to just call their super. Set breakpoints. See where it's hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as my experience goes I've come to terms with the fact that `onActivityResult` is a complete mess.

For your particular situation I believe you should call `startActivityForResult` from fragA via `getParent` method in FragB. Then get the result in FragA and pass it onto the child fragment using `getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()`.

I have followed this pattern for a FragmentTabHost where the individual tabs are child Fragments. There doesn't seem to be any default code to pass the activity result onto child fragments.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experience.